# How to extract notes and attachment for a custom object "X"

Tags: soql, query, data-loader, attachment, dataloader.io

I have tried to download notes and attachment for a custom object under donot get the option to filter notes and attachment for a particular object.

1. Login to http://dataloader.io with your login to Salesforce, it use SSO
2. Click "New Task" and select "Export" button
3. Select Attachment object, click Next
4. You can select just the Body field, or with some fields, or all fields
5. Click "Save & Run"
6. Wait the process

Is there any other way to export the notes and attachment for a particular object

Comment: one parent custom object example "VOB"

Comment: Warning: related objects exports are only available for Batch API

Answer (score 1):

I've done this using workbench.developerforce.com using the soql query functionality, and selecting the 'export as bulk CSV' option.

You can write a query along these lines

Select ID from attachment where parent id in (select ID from yourobject__c)

I've only used this technique to extract name, file type, etc.  I am not sure if you could get the actual body of binary attachments.  Should work for notes also.

Depending on data size you could run into limits on query results, so you may need to add filters or limits or try a different approach depending on what you run into.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Data loader App, DataLodear.io or Workbench you can't export Notes and Attachments directly from specific Objects. You need to check Custom X Object and from each record, you can download Notes & Attachments. This will take more time to download. So you can check faster way for this task. AppExchnage Apps will help you to download Bulk fo Attachments with just a few clicks.

Satrang Mass File Download AppExchange App is doing the same task as you looking for, It's Downloading Notes & Attachments from Standard And Custom Object, User needs to select the Object Name and require ListView or Records or SOQl Querry and then fit the Search Button to download all Notes & Attachments.
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EcsAOUAZ&tab=e

Disclaimer: I work at Satrang Technologies, ​the ​publisher of this Mass File Download AppExchange App.

Answer (score 0):

You can export all notes and attachments using open-source sfdx-hardis plugin command

- First, define a files export

`sfdx hardis:org:configure:files`

When prompted for SOQL request, you can input `SELECT Id,Name FROM MyCustomObjectX__c`

- Then, run the files export

`sfdx hardis:org:files:export`

More details in this [article](https://nicolas.vuillamy.fr/how-to-mass-download-notes-and-attachments-files-from-a-salesforce-org-83a028824afd)

[image]

*Disclaimer: My company authors sfdx-hardis plugin*

Comment: I tried this plugin, but not sure, it downloads only from Documents, not from Attachments, can you please help me with how I can downloads from the Attachment using this plugin command

Comment: @herr this is a known request -> https://github.com/hardisgroupcom/sfdx-hardis/issues/296 . But it would take time to implement it, so until we meet a client use case in Cloudity requiring such enhancement, it will remain a low priority... But we gladly accept pull requests, if you want to contribute :)

Answer (score 0):

You can export Salesforce custom objects and fields using windsor.ai. They have just implemented custom objects export for one of their clients.

Disclaimer: I work for the company though not in the team responsible for Salesforce integration.

Comment: I've downvoted this because you're a new account suggesting a paid product, and there's no clear statement of your affiliation (or lack thereof). Taken together, I find this very suspicious.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I am more active on stackoverflow and used the same account to login to stackoverflow. I do work for the company though not in the team responsible for the Salesforce integration. Have added a disclaimer to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for updating. Downvote retracted.